# Angularjs passing value from one module to another module

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angularjs for my application and I would like to transfer the data between the modules, tried all the ways, but the data is not getting passed. Please have a look at my code here.

1. I have a page called departments in frontapp module, while clicking on particular department, I want to pass the department Id to departmentapp module where each department will have its own page.

   ```
   <a href="./school"><h5>{{school.schoolName}}</h5></a>
   <ul data-ng-repeat="department in school.departments">
   <li data-ng-click="getdepartmentBydepartmentId(department.departmentId);setDepartmentId(department.departmentId)">
       <a href="./department"> {{department.departName}}</a>
   </li>
   ```
2. The code of Controller

   ```
   $scope.getdepartmentBydepartmentId = function(departmentId){
       SchoolService.getdepartmentBydepartmentId(departmentId).then(function(response){
           $scope.department= response.data;
       });
   }

   $scope.getDepartmentId=function(){
       SchoolService.getDepartmentId().then(function(response){
           $scope.departmentId = response.data;
       });
   }

   $scope.setDepartmentId=function(departmentId)
   {
      //Some authentication code...
      alert(departmentId);
      SchoolService.setDepartmentId(departmentId);
      alert(SchoolService.getDepartmentId());

      //Here I want to pass the username to homectrl.js
      window.location.href="./department"
   }
   ```
3. The code in services js file

   ```
   obj.getDepartmentId=function(){
       return departmentIDSchool;
   };

   obj.setDepartmentId=function(departmentID){
       // var departmentID = null;
       departmentIDSchool = departmentID;
   };

   obj.getdepartmentBydepartmentId=function(departmentId){
       return $http.post('getdepartmentBydepartmentId?departmentId='+departmentId);
   };
   ```
4. In departmentapp module - departmentcontroller.js

   ```
   app.controller("SchoolController", SchoolController);
   app.service("SchoolService",SchoolService);
   angular.module("frontApp").SchoolService.getDepartmentId().then(function(response){
       $scope.departmentId = response.data;
       alert($scope.departmentId);
   });
   ```

But here departmentId I am not getting. After going through many questions at stack overflow, I come to know that in service layer we need to have getter and setter, but even after placing that it is not working. Can some one help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable like that easily in the router

```
    $routeProvider.when('/:primaryNav/:secondaryNav', {
        templateUrl: 'resources/angular/templates/nav/'+$routeParams.primaryNav+'/'+$routeParams.secondaryNav+'.html'
    });
```

See the $routeParams in templateUrl, you can also inject it into your controller to get the params.